# How to tell if $a_n$ is less than $b_n$ in a comparison test?

Tags: calculus

More specifically, when using the comparison test how can you tell which one is bigger when comparing the $a_n$ and your $b_n$?

Comment: In general, you cannot. If you have a more specific situation in mind, you will get more effective answers by editing your question to reflect that

Comment: Yes this is far too general to have an answer.

Comment: @EricStucky so lets say I have A=(N^(2)+4)/(N(N^2+5)) AND B=1/N

Comment: If we're using the (series) comparison test, we're probably hoping that $B_N$ is smaller, so let's pretend that's true: then we have $$\frac{N^2+4}{N(N^2+5)}\geq\frac{1}{N}.$$ Now you can solve this inequality for $N$ to find the values of $N$ for which the inequality is true. Ideally you'll want it to be something like $N\geq 1$; if not, try multiplying your choice of $B_N$ by some constant, before changing your guess really dramatically. (WARNING: to use the series comparison test, you must also check that your sequences are positive numbers!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the comparison test is that you **pick** a nice smaller/larger series.

If you are not able to tell which is bigger/smaller, maybe you didn't pick the right comparison.

Last but not least, in most situations the Limit Comparison Test is easier to use than the comparison test.